# What is the difference betwwen the older alloctaor::construct and the new one and explicit constructor?

Tags: c++, allocator

As I know `std::allocator<T>::construct` takes only two parameters on older version of C++; the first is a pointer to raw, un-constructed memory in which we want to construct an object of type `T` and the second one is a value of element type to initialize that object. So the copy-constructor is invoked:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int, int) { cout << "Foo(int, int)" << endl; }
    /*explicit*/ Foo(int) { cout << "Foo(int)" << endl; }
    Foo(const Foo&) { cout << "Foo(const Foo&)" << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


    allocator<Foo> a;
    Foo* const p = a.allocate(200, NULL); // second parameter is required on C++98 but on C++11 it is optional
//  Foo* const p = a.allocate(200); // works fine on C++11 but not on C++98

    a.construct(p, 5, 7); // works on C++ 11 and up but not C++98
    a.construct(p, 10);// works on both
    a.destroy(p);
    a.destroy(p + 1);
    a.deallocate(p, 200);



    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

- Why on C++98 `a.construct(p, 10)` calling the copy constructor but on C++11 and above is calling just the constructor that takes an integer?
- Does this mean on C++ 11 because of some Copy-elision optimization even if the constructor `Foo(int)` is `explicit` works on such call: `a.construct(p, 5)` works on C++11 even the constructor is `explicit` what I am sure of is it doesn't works on C++98 if `Foo(int)` is `explicit`.
- If so then if I compile that statement with some sort of disabling `copy-elision` optimization will cause the compiler fail? Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: until C++11, there was no _perfect fowarding_. Details provided below by @flyx. Note that there is _no copy elision_ involved (no pass-by-value or return-by-value).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because the declaration of `construct` [changed in C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct):

```
void construct( pointer p, const_reference val );  (1)  (until C++11)
template< class U, class... Args >
void construct( U* p, Args&&... args );            (2)  (since C++11)
```

The first declaration calls the copy constructor, while the second declaration calls a constructor that matches the given list of arguments. This could be the copy constructor, but also another constructor as you saw in your code.

`a.construct(p, 10)` calls the copy constructor in C++98 because the `10` is implicitly converted to `Foo` via the `Foo(int)` constructor. This conversion is not necessary in C++11 since there is a matching constructor that takes an `int` (exactly the constructor that was used for converting in C++98). This is also the reason why the code doesn't work in C++98 when you add `explicit` – it cannot convert the `10` to a `Foo` then.